# how to change "kind" of files in OSX mavericks?

Tags: finder, filesystem

I have assigned Text Wrangler as the default app for all my **.srt** files (right click on one of the files -> get info -> open with Text Wrangler -> change all).

My confusion is that even though I have done this, in Finder some of the (.srt) files show as "Text file" while most show as "TextWrangler document".

I've remove all the .DS_Store files in my volume but still no change.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

In saying that, double-clicking on the .srt files marked as "text file" still opens them in Text Wrangler.

thanks a lot

Comment: as mentioned in the 1st sentence, these are .srt files.

Answer (score 1):

File type associations are cached by [LaunchServices](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19185170#19185170) and can become corrupt.

Try opening /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and entering this command:

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

After the command finishes, log out of your user account, and log back in

---

srt files, which are SubRip Text (SRT) files, are actually [plain text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.srt#SubRip_text_file_format) files. You can use the [*file* command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app to see that this is so:

```
      chillin@stack:~$
      chillin@stack:~$
      chillin@stack:~$ curl -O http://www.sub-titles.net/static/podnapisi/a/6/d/a6d482118f7790cad9926336c3f667e87618040e.zip
      chillin@stack:~$ unzip a6d482118f7790cad9926336c3f667e87618040e.zip
      Archive:  a6d482118f7790cad9926336c3f667e87618040e.zip
      inflating: Snowpiercer.2013.720p.BluRay.DTS.x264-PublicHD.srt
      chillin@stack:~$ file Snowpiercer.2013.720p.BluRay.DTS.x264-PublicHD.srt
      Snowpiercer.2013.720p.BluRay.DTS.x264-PublicHD.srt: ASCII English text, with CRLF line terminators
      chillin@stack:~$
      chillin@stack:~$ echo; echo '     Stack Exchange RULES!'; echo

           Stack Exchange RULES!

      chillin@stack:~$
      chillin@stack:~$
```

---

[Show and hide filename extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140525014202/http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13920)

[Two ways to do it](http://osxdaily.com/2013/08/08/change-default-application-open-files-mac-os-x/)

[How to clear custom application associations in OS X](http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-clear-custom-application-associations-in-os-x/)

Comment: I'll try your suggestion tonight. thanks! ps. I do know srt files are text files. just want to make them appear as TextWrangler documents for easier sorting by kind.